# Alexa Skill: Playing Audio results in "Sorry don't know that"

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am coding my very first alexa skill and am very excited!  I am trying to make a skill so that when I say "ramranch", alexa will play Sunil Syal. I started this skill using the space fact picker blueprint. I have deleted that code and put in my own. The aws is connected and is working, however when I say "ramranch" in the testing console, Alexa responds with "Sorry, I don't know that". Their is no debug or error message.

```
/* eslint-disable  func-names */
/* eslint-disable  no-console */

const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');

const RamRanch = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'LaunchRequest'
    || (request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && request.intent.name === 'handle');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    this.emit(':tell', "Let's enjoy a world's most beautiful composition, composed by the great, Sunil Syal, <audio src='https://my-apis.000webhostapp.com/audio/Romantic%20Solitude-Instrumental%20(Flute).mp3'/> Wow, That is amazing. Click the link on top right corner to listen to full song.");
  }
}
const HelpHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(HELP_MESSAGE)
      .reprompt(HELP_REPROMPT)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

const ExitHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;
    return request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && (request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
        || request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
```

Comment: maybe it doesn't think you're saying ramranch

Comment: ah well you see you actually type in the words into the console whenyour building/testing the skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a strong likelihood that when you modified the blueprint skill you may have deleted the node modules. Here is a slightly modified version of your index.js code. Begin a node project npm init. next npm install ask-sdk. your project folder will now have node_modules, package-lock.json, and package.json add this index.js file.

```
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'LaunchRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit, you can say what about ramranch';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Ramranch', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
const RamranchIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'ramranchIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Lets enjoy a worlds most beautiful composition, composed by the great, Sunil Syal, <audio src="https://my-apis.000webhostapp.com/audio/Romantic%20Solitude-Instrumental%20(Flute).mp3"/> Wow, That is amazing. Click the link on top right corner to listen to full song.';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Ramranch', speechText)
      .getResponse();

  }
};
const HelpIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'You can say what about Ramranch!';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Ramranch', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
const CancelAndStopIntentHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
      && (handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent'
        || handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'AMAZON.StopIntent');
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Goodbye!';

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard('Ramranch', speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
const SessionEndedRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest';
  },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    //any cleanup logic goes here
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.getResponse();
  }
};
const ErrorHandler = {
  canHandle() {
    return true;
  },
  handle(handlerInput, error) {
    console.log(`Error handled: ${error.message}`);

    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak('Sorry, I can\'t understand the command. Please say again.')
      .reprompt('Sorry, I can\'t understand the command. Please say again.')
      .getResponse();
  },
};

exports.handler = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom()
  .addRequestHandlers(
    LaunchRequestHandler,
    RamranchIntentHandler,
    HelpIntentHandler,
    CancelAndStopIntentHandler,
    SessionEndedRequestHandler)
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .lambda();
```

Be sure to modify your Alexa skill developer model to include a ramranchIntent as I have not combined launch and primary intents as in your code. Lastly, zip this with the other previously mentioned files into your lambda function in AWS and add some intent phrases for triggering Ramranch, in my tests I used this skill JSON

```
{
    "interactionModel": {
        "languageModel": {
            "invocationName": "ramranch player",
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.FallbackIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "AMAZON.NavigateHomeIntent",
                    "samples": []
                },
                {
                    "name": "ramranchIntent",
                    "slots": [],
                    "samples": [
                        "what about ramranch",
                        "lets hear ramranch"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "types": []
        }
    }
}
```